# I can't fill 'input' and 'textarea'

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with `<input>` and `<textarea>` tag.

I'm trying to receive a information by clients, but those tags does not work.

I cannot click the fields, and fill the fields with texts.

Only cursor changes into `I` when the mouse is hovering the fields.

I don't know what is the problem..

I didn't change any settings for texts, but it doesn't work.

I'm using those fields with HTML which use Three.js.

Please help me.

Below codes are whole about it.

It's just pop-up.

```css
.userInfo {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea class='userInfo' id='userName' placeholder='Name'></textarea>
  <!--  <input type='text' style='color:black;' class='userInfo' id='userName' /> I tried textarea becuase 
                                                                                 input tag does not work.-->
</div>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: add textarea and input without id and class, then check !

Comment: Codes working fine there must be some script which prevent user to type in

Comment: @AnandhukrishnaVR I see... After I asked this question, I made a new html, and it works fine.. Like Awais said, there must be some scripts... It is really hard to find it omg..

Comment: @Awais same replied..

Comment: I set the label for it, and I clicked it, I can fill it now!
But I don't want to create any label for it..

Comment: @EugeneFitzher Check you `header` where you include script there must be a script in which validator of input fields present

Comment: inspect that elements class and id's css then you can find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseup', funMouseUp, true);

function funMouseUp()
{
//    event.preventDefault(); // IT WAS THE PROBLEM

    ...
}
```

And also on mousedown event.

`event.preventDefault();` was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked and the code is working fine. Maybe try a different browser or restart your browser or clear cache and try, hopefully, it should work.

See below snippet, it's working fine:

```css
.userInfo{
  vertical-align:middle;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <textarea class='userInfo' id='userName' placeholder='Name'></textarea>
  <input type='text' style='color:black;' class='userInfo' id='userName' />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just check it here.. it works fine here.. but mine doesn't work.... Is there a some settings for disable input from the clients? :sad:

Comment: I set the label for it, and I clicked it, I can fill it now!
But I don't want to create any label for it..

Comment: Solved!
mousedown event -> `event.preventDefault();` was the problem. ( which for three.js )

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too sure what the issue is could you include the entire code, I got a three.js cdn and linked it to a page with your snippet and everything is working as it should.

Comment: I set the label for it, and I clicked it, I can fill it now!
But I don't want to create any label for it..

Comment: If you set a label just set no text or hidden.